# Concrete5 - How do I get the selected template inside my block controller?

Tags: concrete5

I'm using Concrete5 5.6.0 and trying to make my `Block` more customisable by using LESS.

I followed the information here: http://www.codeblog.ch/2014/01/concrete5-use-less-files-for-block-templates/ and Remo's code that it links to but `getCurrentTemplate()` does not exist on the `Controller`

What is the correct way for me to get the current template to work with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a snippet of code in this howto to get the current template name. Not a complete solution, but maybe it will provide some ideas.

http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/developers/load-template-specific-assets/

Answer (score 1):

This will work in 5.7

```
$b = $this->getBlockObject();
if (is_object($b)) {
    $bvt = new BlockViewTemplate($b);
    if (is_object($bvt)) {
        $templatepath = $bvt->getTemplate();
        list($junk, $template) = explode('/templates', $templatepath);
        if (strlen($template) > 0) {    // any template name left ?
            // $template holds the rest of the path with the template name
        } else {
            // standard template
        }
    }
}
```